# Parsing JSON to form using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

I am trying to parse this JSON into a form:

```
{
    "School": ["school1", "school2", "school3"],
    "Year": ["year1", "year2", "year3"],
    "GPA": ["gpa1", "gpa2", "gpa3"]
}
```

This is the desired form output:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input name="School" type="text" value="school1">
        <input name="Year" type="text" value="year1">
        <input name="GPA" type="text" value="gpa1">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="School" type="text" value="school2">
        <input name="Year" type="text" value="year2">
        <input name="GPA" type="text" value="gpa2">
    </li>
    <li>
        <input name="School" type="text" value="school3">
        <input name="Year" type="text" value="year3">
        <input name="GPA" type="text" value="gpa3">
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I parse this JSON into a format like this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in PHP? If so, why the "javascript" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really need to transpose the array values (i.e. swap rows and columns) to make this simple. Since there is no transpose function in PHP (at least as far as I know), you need to either write your own function, or just loop through the array values manually, perhaps like this:

```
<?php

$json = <<<_
{ "School": ["school1", "school2", "school3"],
  "Year": ["year1", "year2", "year3"],
  "GPA": ["gpa1", "gpa2", "gpa3"]
}
_;

$a = json_decode ($json, true); /* decode as associative array */

if (is_array ($a)) {
  $names = array_keys ($a);
  $values = array_values ($a);
  $rows = count ($names);
  $cols = count ($values[0]); /* assuming all rows have the same amount of values */
  echo "<ul>\n";

  for ($c = 0; $c < $cols; $c++) {
    echo "    <li>\n";
    for ($r = 0; $r < $rows; $r++) {
      $n = htmlspecialchars ($names[$r]);
      $v = htmlspecialchars ($values[$r][$c]);
      echo <<<_
        <input name="$n" type="text" value="$v">

_;
    }
    /* echo "    </li>\n"; // Redundant tag */
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
} else {
  /* Error decoding JSON */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = your json object;
$array = json_decode($json, true);  // It will return you an array
```

To use the above array use `foreach()` like:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    // here $key contains School, Year, GPA in it and $value is an array that contains ["gpa1", "gpa2", "gpa3"] in it. To use it use an additional foreach() and put the html accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On way which is possible is to modify the decoded json as per the layout which is required in the problem statement. Assuming your structure of JSON remains the same.

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "School": ["school1", "school2", "school3"],
    "Year": ["year1", "year2", "year3"],
    "GPA": ["gpa1", "gpa2", "gpa3"]
}';

$decodedJson = json_decode($json, true); # it will generate associative array

# helper array to customize the array elements
$records = [];

foreach ($decodedJson as $key => $value) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
        $records[$i][] = $val;
        $i++;
    }
}
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach ($records as $value) {?>
    <li>
        <input name="School" type="text" value="<?php echo $value[0]?>">
        <input name="School" type="text" value="<?php echo $value[1]?>">
        <input name="School" type="text" value="<?php echo $value[2]?>">
    </li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
```